# Build Sip Client using Sip Servlet as signalling

Tags: java, jain-sip, sip-servlet, mobicents-sip-servlets

I am using mobicent sip servlet and I have deployed it in JBOSS as7 successfully. But I saw testing is from the sip softphones.

I have google search alot about building our own sip client but I cannot find the proper guide.

What I have to do is using Sip Servlet as a signalling and I have to create Android client(using JAIN-SIP) and also I have to create UAC from browser.

I am confuse about how can I use my Sip Servlet application that is running on server? How I send requests(Register,Invite and so on) from client to sip servlet?

**For Example** [this tutorial](http://www.telestax.com/mobicents-sip-servlets-sip-programming-in-java-tutorial/) But How I create my client? :)

A little guide or small tutorial about create UAC or how to use sip servlet can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has built in very simple SIP client and APIs here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html. You only need your own JAIN-SIP in android if you are using some more advanced features. There are plenty of examples here https://svn.java.net/svn/jsip~svn/trunk/src/examples

Comment: Can i also use simple webrtc and sip servlet signalling?

Comment: Yes but you need to use the native webrtc library for android. I suppose writing your own webrtc stack is not feasible. You should check the android examples in the webrtc community and grab a recent build from there. It may not be very stable yet and wont work on all devices. http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/android

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting studying this example https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/tree/master/sip-servlets-examples/websocket-b2bua

This is the Sip Servlets application behind the bundled WebRTC demo that comes with Mobicents SIP Servlets : https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/wiki/HTML5WebRTCVideoApplication

This demo connects 2 WebRTC browsers together to have a video or audio call.

In your case, you'll need to replace one of the browsers with an Android based Client. I would recommend looking at an Android SDK that supports WebRTC. We started building one at https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk which is based on JAIN-SIP but the media side doesn't fully support WebRTC yet. (Any contributions are welcome though) Altough you can use it for chat/messaging to start with and show it works.

Comment: I am glad to see your answer :) .. Can you tell me, How to setup start converstion after establishment of media session between the client? Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293713/how-to-start-rtp-stream-inside-a-sip-sdp-call  .I will Appreciate your answer

Comment: The SIP protocol is a signalling protocol which allows to exchange details (what is called the SDP) for setting up the Media between the peers. The example I described above https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets/wiki/HTML5WebRTCVideoApplication does just that the communication is then Peer To Peer ie that the Clients exchange media without going through a Media Server. I would recommend playing a bit with it and analyzing the traffic with wireshark to see how things are working and get a better understanding before moving on to implement the Android SDK.